# Login Form React JS With Custom Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently in the process of learning React JS.[Tutorial D.O](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-login-authentication-to-react-applications#step-2-%E2%80%94-creating-a-token-api)
I already have a PHP backend before and I want to create a login form where the result of the backend is JWT.
I use a custom hook in React JS for that.
Here is the code that I created.

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { Routes } from "../config";
import { useToken } from "../hooks";
import Login from "./Login";

const App = () => {

  const { token, setToken } = useToken();

  if (!token) {
    return <Login setToken={setToken} />;
  }

  return <Routes />;
};
export default App;
```

**useToken()**

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function useToken() {
  const getToken = () => {
    const tokenString = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken?.token;
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

  const saveToken = (userToken) => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken.token);
  };

  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token,
  };
}
```

**Login/index.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Button, Card, Col, Container, Form, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./login.css";

async function loginUser(credentials) {
  const url = "v1/auth";
  const user = new FormData();
  user.append("username", credentials.username);
  user.append("password", credentials.password);

  return fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: user,
  }).then((data) => data.json());
}

export default function Login({ setToken }) {
  const [username, setUserName] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

  // Handle submit
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const token = await loginUser({ username, password });
    setToken(token);
  };

  return (
    <div id="login-page">
      <Container>
        <Row className="d-flex justify-content-md-center align-items-center vh-100">
          <Col sm={12} md={6}>
            <Card>
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Card.Header>Sign In</Card.Header>
                <Card.Body>
                  <Form.Group controlId="loginform-username">
                    <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Username"
                      name="username"
                      onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group controlId="loginform-password">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                      name="password"
                      type="password"
                      placeholder="Password"
                      onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                </Card.Body>
                <Card.Footer>
                  <Button
                    variant="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    className="float-right"
                  >
                    Login
                  </Button>
                  <div className="clearfix"></div>
                </Card.Footer>
              </Form>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

Login.propTypes = {
  setToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

When I login successfully, I save the token to local storage. But I got the following warning.

```
index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `setToken` is marked as required in `Login`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

How to solve this?. Any help it so appreciated

**Updated**

**Routes**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Login, Home } from "../../pages";

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Routes` you call `Login` but never pass it `setToken`, which is required. One option is to pass the `setToken` function down through `Routes`:

**App.js**

```js
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { Routes } from "../config";
import { useToken } from "../hooks";
import Login from "./Login";

const App = () => {

  const { token, setToken } = useToken();

  if (!token) {
    return <Login setToken={setToken} />;
  }

  return <Routes setToken={setToken} />;
};
export default App;
```

**Routes.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Login, Home } from "../../pages";

const Routes = ({ setToken }) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login setToken={setToken} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Route path="/login">
          <Login /> /* <--- this line is calling Login component but is passing setToken as undefined */
</Route>
```